# Stored Procedure com if

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

tenho uma tabela com os campos nome, id e salario.

Preciso de uma procedure que altere o salario do funcionário, caso ela receba um, deve aumentar em 300 reais o salario, em caso de outro valor diminuir o salario em 500 reais.

Sabem como isso pode ser feito?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Imagina que a resolução seja algo nesta linha:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE AumentarSalario(IN quantidade INT, codigoFuncionario INT)
BEGIN
    IF quantidade = 1 THEN
            <update que aumenta salario em 300 usando o codigoFuncionario recebido>
    ELSE
            <update que aumenta salario em 500 usando o codigoFuncionario recebido>
    END IF
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Deixei espaço para os comando serem inserido por não possuir certeza da estrutura de banco e ter recebido poucos detalhes.

Comment: tenho uma tabela com campo id e nome do produto e valor, preciso de uma function que receba por parâmetro o id do produto e a porcentagem de aumento no valor do produto e depois me retorne o valor atual do produto alterado

Comment: Esta duvida deve ser feita em outra pergunta, porém não parece que está a tentar.

Comment: sim mas so posso publicar de 40 em 40 minutos me ajuda ai mano vida ou morte!!! @LuizSantos me ajuda por favor

Comment: liberou, mas aconselho a tentar mais, antes de pedir a solução.

Comment: estou fazendo uma prova fica dificil kkkkk